# Django backend died when deploying a new version: Address already in use

Tags: debian, systemd, python, deployment

I have a Django app running on a Debian server, with a simple deploy script that is automatically invoked via a GitHub webhook:

```
#!/bin/sh
git pull
/home/criticalnotes/.local/bin/poetry install --with prod --sync
/home/criticalnotes/.local/bin/poetry run ./manage.py migrate
sudo /usr/sbin/service api.critical-notes.com restart
echo "service api.critical-notes.com restarted"
```

So this deploy script pulls the latest code from git, installs the dependencies, runs the migrate script, and then restarts the service.

My `api.critical-notes.com.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=api.critical-notes.com

[Service]
User=criticalnotes
Group=criticalnotes
Restart=on-failure
WorkingDirectory=/home/criticalnotes/api.critical-notes.com
ExecStart=/home/criticalnotes/.local/bin/poetry run uvicorn criticalnotes.asgi:application --log-level warning --workers 8 --uds /tmp/uvicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This setup has worked perfectly fine for a pretty long time, but today when I pushed new code to GitHub the site stopped working. After looking into what was going on, I noticed that the `api.critical-notes.com` service wasn't running any more, it kept dying with failures, and when trying to start the backend manually I got this error:

```
Address already in use
```

I have no idea what caused this problem, especially since this has never happened before and I have not made any deploy or setup changes today (or any time recently). So my question is how this could have happened - how could the address still be in use when the backend was not running? And secondly, how can I improve my deploy script so this can't happen again?

It was quite scary to have to site be offline because the backend was offline, for about 30 minutes while I was trying to figure out why my code push broke things. I don't want that to happen again

Comment: The same happened again today: after deploying new code, the backend was down and the site was just showing an error 500 because of that. I really don't understand why this deploy method doesn't work any longer.

Comment: You need to specify where you found that error, and include the whole line if you didn't (plus context if available). You might get lucky and have someone who uses your exact stack swing by and recognize the issue from that, but otherwise it's a pretty vague error. In terms of general webserver troubleshooting, I could imagine half a dozen possible causes off the top of my head, and I personally can't rule any of them out from just this. It would also help if you specified the general communications flow and what you mean by "backend". I see uvicorn in the execstart, is that what you mean?

Comment: I got that error when manually running `/home/criticalnotes/.local/bin/poetry run uvicorn criticalnotes.asgi:application --log-level warning --workers 8 --uds /tmp/uvicorn.sock`. That was the whole line.

Comment: And with backend I just mean my Django application, which is an API (backend) for my website (frontend).

Comment: Ok, I see. There is still a lot going on here. This could be poetry complaining directly, or a nested error from the command you're trying to run (uvicorn). I've actually never heard of `poetry` before, so I just assumed that was a custom script until I reread it in your comment just now. Regardless, you are chaining 3 programs together here (not including python): poetry, uvicorn, and then your application. The only way to investigate further is to figure out which of them is throwing this error, either by stepping through execution and/or enabling/examining their respective logs.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the application and deployment process, this is almost impossible to answer with any certainty. Common issues are things like conflicting configuration scripts, using ports in a reserved range, or a lingering process that's holding onto the desired binding from a previous restart. If you've updated any required libraries/dependencies in the last few months (e.g. uvicorn, python, etc), they may have changed their configuration defaults such that you need to specify an additional parameter now to make things work. It could also be related to the UDS file, especially if your startup script expects to create it. If it's still locked open for whatever reason, that would likely trigger an error like this. Without knowing how that socket is used, the root cause of the file hanging open could be an error literally almost anywhere in your code. (Or any dependencies that've been updated since this last worked.)

If I notice you add more details I'll try to come back and edit this with a more specific answer, but I hope this at least points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

> Address already in use

Is really the only thing you need to consider here. You didn't say what address (specificaly the port) the service uses. If its a web service then these will likely by 80 and/or 443. You need to find out what is using those ports. Depending on the version of debian you are using the comands for this would be (as root) `netstat -nap | grep :80` or `ss -nlp | grep :80`.

You can also check if anything is listening on the relevant port using `nc -zv localhost 80`

(repeat for 443)

If there really is nothing listening there, then it sounds as if your server is trying to start itself twice.

You might also have a look at the output of `systemctl status api.critical-notes.com` and see what happens when you run `systemctl restart api.critical-notes.com` from a terminal session.